# Problem when re-rendering a screen (useEffect/useCallback)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

On an app I'm working on, I have to change the language of the app based on what the user chose. I have one language selector for non-registered users and another one for registered users.

The code for the selector looks like this

```
const LanguageSelect: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const language = useLanguage();
  const currentUser = useCurrentUser();
  const { updateUser } = props;

  const updateLanguage = useCallback((currentUser, language) => {
    updateUser(currentUser.set('language', language));
  }, [currentUser, language]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      try {
        updateLanguage(currentUser, language);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }
  }, [language, currentUser, updateLanguage]);

  return (
    <Select
      background={Color.minimalWhite}
      useBorderRadius={true}
      onValueChange={props.setLocalizationFunction}
      items={languageDictionary}
      value={languageDictionary.find((lan) => lan.value === language).label}
    />
  );
}
```

The problem is that when a user selects a language when they're not logged in, and then has another language selected when they're logged in (for example, first they select english when not logged in, then french when they're logged in), when the Home screen for a logged in user is rendered, it gets re-rendered almost immediately. I don't know what's going on, I even tried all kinds of stuff to make the `useEffect` on the languageSelector to run only once, however, the screen gets re-rendered all the time. How can I make the `useEffect` to run only once whenever the user gets logged in or they change the language by themselves to prevent automatic re-rendering?

Comment: Can you share a codepen?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we have enough to go on here. Not knowing what `useLanguage`, `useCurrentUser`, `updateUser`, and what is this `set` on the current user object? Taking a stab I'm going to guess that when someone logs in, the effect runs and sets the language on the user, which causes a new currentUser record every time. Although seems like that'd be an infinite loop. Simply not setting the current user's language if it already matches language maybe solves that?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use a store like react-redux.  That way you have a single "selected language" and it can be accessed throughout the application.